# Disable beeping in lightdm

Tags: lightdm, bell

When typing backspace in an empty password box in lightdm, noisy beep sound comes out. Is there a way to mute this beeping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to turn off the beep with `xset b off`.

This can be made to take effect for the lightdm greeter by adding it to the `greeter-setup-script` line of the `lightdm.conf` file at `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`.

Edit your `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` config file to look like the following:

```
[Seat:*]
# ...
greeter-setup-script=xset b off
```

**Gotcha:** Ensure that you edit your `greeter-setup-script` setting in your `[Seat:*]` table, otherwise the setting won't take affect—see https://linux.debian.bugs.dist.narkive.com/2p9KbtdF/bug-686264-lightdm-greeter-setup-script-not-executed#post6 post.